# nokogiri fails in text contains

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to extract text out of a html.

`doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<B> <A href="http://www.asl.com/foo/bar"> Status :</A></B> REGISTERED                                        <BR>')`

```
puts doc.search('//b').first.text
puts doc.search('//b[contains(text(),"Status")]/following-sibling::text()[1]').first.text
```

the first puts returns `Status :`
But the second puts throws an exception `undefined method 'text' for nil:NilClass`

Why the `contains` doesn't search properly ?
or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea of the `text` function in XPath. Unlike the DOM function it does not return a concatenated string of all text sub-nodes. Instead it selects individual text nodes.

In your example `//text()` would select three text nodes:

```
 [" ", " Status :", " REGISTERED "]
```

What you might want is this XPath expression:

```
//b/a[contains(text(),"Status")]/../following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Essentially it finds the `a` element having the correct text node, than walks up to the parent element (`b`) and then gets its sibling text node.

Comment: It's a shorthand for the `parent` axis.

Comment: no about text() but . does which is probably closer to what he was going for: doc.search('//b[contains(.,"Status")]/following-sibling::text()').first

Answer (score 1):

The "Status: " isn't actually a text node inside `<B></B>`, it's a text node inside `<A></A>`.

```
doc.search('//b/a[contains(text(),"Status")]/text()[1]').first.text
```

Works for me.

Comment: .text returns not the html content but the content that would be displayed IMHO . so it should work that way since already `('//b').text` returns `Status`

Comment: Yes, but XPath itself doesn't work like that... that's just nokogiri being helpful.  You're evaluating `text()` of the `<b>` in your xpath query ;)

Comment: also I am trying to get the next sibling of `<b>` tag and the output should be `Registered` in this case . how can I do using your code ?